# If statement returning undefined

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to get this function to show 'true' or 'false' depending on my if-statement.
The function should return boolean 'true' if
'value' is greater than 'rangeStart' and less than 'rangeStop'. Otherwise
it should return boolean 'false'.

```
var inRange = function(rangeStart3,rangeStop3,value) {
    if (value > rangeStart3&&value < rangeStop3)
    return inRange;
};

ANSWER = inRange(167,521,264)
```

I'm getting answer "undefined" and not sure what I'm doing wrong.
I would also like to add that I'm very new to Javascript!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the useless `if`:

```
var inRange = function(rangeStart3, rangeStop3, value) {
    return (value > rangeStart3 && value < rangeStop3);
};
```

The reason that the existing code resulted in `undefined` is because when the condition of that `if` was false the code ran the implicit `return undefined;` that exists at the end of every function.

Answer (score 0):

This will return if both the value is bigger than the rangestart and value is less than the rangestop.

```
if (value > rangeStart3 && value < rangeStop3) return true
else return false
```

Or you could write it with less code.

```
return (value > rangeStart3 && value < rangeStop3);
```

`return inRange` should be avoided. This is an undefined variable, besides it is also the name of the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

you havent added the return value if the case is not within in

```
var inRange = function(rangeStart3,rangeStop3,value) {
    return (value > rangeStart3 && value < rangeStop3);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

More written out and self explanatory solution:

```
var inRange = function(rangeStart3,rangeStop3,value) {
    if (value > rangeStart3&&value < rangeStop3) {
                return true;
              }
      else {
              return false;
   }
};
```

Comment: if(true) return true else false?